problem with MiniLibX library project for visualization of 3d maps into 2d
So this is my code without the key_event and mlx initiation. I guess the main problem is that I first tried to make it dynamic and get the size for the map from the file but then I realized that this size is changing and then I rewrote the code with a fixed window but I guess I forgot something and everything go to hell...
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    t_data  data;

    if (ac != 2)
    {
        ft_printf ("use an fdf map");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    get_map_dim (av[1], &data.map_width, &data.map_height);
    data.map = allocate_map(data.map_width, data.map_height);
    parse_fdf_file (&data, av[1]);
    data.win_width = WIN_WIDTH;
    data.win_height = WIN_HEIGHT;
    data.rot_angle_x = 0;
    data.rot_angle_y = 0;
    data.rot_angle_z = 0;
    calculate_scaling_and_offset(&data);
    if (init_mlx (&data) == EXIT_FAILURE)
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    draw_map (&data);
    mlx_key_hook (data.win_ptr, handle_keypress, &data);
    mlx_loop (data.mlx_ptr);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void    draw_pixel(t_data *data, int x, int y, int color)
{
    if (x >= 0 && x < data->win_width && y >= 0 && y < data->win_height)
        mlx_pixel_put (data->mlx_ptr, data->win_ptr, x, y, color);
    else
        ft_printf ("pixel out of bounds: x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
}

void    init_bresenham(t_coords *coords, t_bresenham *bres)
{
    bres->dx = fabs(coords->x1 - coords->x0);
    bres->dy = fabs(coords->y1 - coords->y0);
    if (coords->x0 < coords->x1)
        bres->sx = 1;
    else
        bres->sx = -1;
    if (coords->y0 < coords->y1)
        bres->sy = 1;
    else
        bres->sy = -1;
    bres->err = bres->dx - bres->dy;
}

void    draw_line(t_data *data, t_coords *coords, t_bresenham *bres)
{
    while (1)
    {
        draw_pixel (data, coords->x0, coords->y0, 0xFFFFFF);
        if (coords->x0 == coords->x1 && coords->y0 == coords->y1)
            break;
        bres->e2 = 2 *bres->err;
        if (bres->e2 > -bres->dy)
        {
            bres->err -= bres->dy;
            coords->x0 += bres->sx;
        }
        if (bres->e2 < bres->dx)
        {
            bres->err += bres->dx;
            coords->y0 += bres->sy;
        }
    }
}

void bresenham(t_data *data, t_coords *coords)
{
    t_bresenham bres;
    
    init_bresenham(coords, &bres);
    draw_line(data, coords, &bres);
}

void isometric_prj(t_coords *coords)
{
    double prev_x;
    double prev_y;
    double prev_z;
    double iso_x;
    double iso_y;

    prev_x = coords->x0;
    prev_y = coords->y0;
    prev_z = coords->z0;
    coords->y0 = prev_y * cos(coords->angle_x) - prev_z * sin(coords->angle_x);  // Rotate around X-axis
    coords->z0 = prev_y * sin(coords->angle_x) + prev_z * cos(coords->angle_x);
    prev_x = coords->x0; // Rotate around Y-axis
    prev_z = coords->z0;
    coords->x0 = prev_x * cos(coords->angle_y) + prev_z * sin(coords->angle_y);
    coords->z0 = -prev_x * sin(coords->angle_y) + prev_z * cos(coords->angle_y);
    prev_x = coords->x0;     // Rotate around Z-axis
    prev_y = coords->y0;
    coords->x0 = prev_x * cos(coords->angle_z) - prev_y * sin(coords->angle_z);
    coords->y0 = prev_x * sin(coords->angle_z) + prev_y * cos(coords->angle_z);
    iso_x = (coords->x0 - coords->y0) * cos(0.523599);   // Isometric projection
    iso_y = coords->z0 + (coords->x0 + coords->y0) * sin(0.523599);
    coords->x0 = iso_x;
    coords->y0 = iso_y;
}

void    init_coords(t_coords *coords, int scale_x, int scale_y, int scale_z) {
    coords->x0 = scale_x;
    coords->y0 = scale_y;
    coords->z0 = scale_z;
}

void    rotate_and_project(t_coords *coords, double scale, int offset_x, int offset_y)
{
    isometric_prj(coords);
    coords->x0 = coords->x0 * scale;
    coords->y0 = coords->y0 * scale;
    coords->x0 = (int)(coords->x0 + offset_x);
    coords->y0 = (int)(coords->y0 + offset_y);
}

void draw_line_between_points(t_data *data, t_coords *coords) 
{
    bresenham(data, coords);
}

void    draw_lines_from_point(t_data *data, t_coords *coords, int x, int y) {
    int scale_x;
    int scale_y;
    int scale_z;

    if (x < data->map_width - 1)
    {
        scale_x = (x + 1) * data->scale;
        scale_y = (y - data->map[y][x + 1]) * data->scale;
        scale_z = data->map[y][x + 1] * data->scale;
        init_coords(coords, scale_x, scale_y, scale_z);
        rotate_and_project(coords, data->scale, data->offset_x, data->offset_y);
        draw_line_between_points(data, coords);
    }
    if (y < data->map_height - 1)
    {
        scale_x = x * data->scale;
        scale_y = (y + 1 - data->map[y + 1][x]) * data->scale;
        scale_z = data->map[y + 1][x] * data->scale;
        init_coords(coords, scale_x, scale_y, scale_z);
        rotate_and_project(coords, data->scale, data->offset_x, data->offset_y);
        draw_line_between_points(data, coords);
    }
}

void    draw_map(t_data *data)
{
    t_coords    coords;
    int         x;
    int         y;
    int         scale_x;
    int         scale_y;
    int         scale_z;

    coords.angle_x = data->rot_angle_x;
    coords.angle_y = data->rot_angle_y;
    coords.angle_z = data->rot_angle_z;
    y = 0;
    while (y < data->map_height)
    {
        x = 0;
        while (x < data->map_width)
        {
            scale_x = x * data->scale;
            scale_y = (y + 1 - data->map[y + 1][x]) * data->scale;
            scale_z = data->map[y + 1][x] * data->scale;
            init_coords(&coords, scale_x, scale_y, scale_z);
            rotate_and_project(&coords, data->scale, data->offset_x, data->offset_y);
            draw_lines_from_point(data, &coords, x, y);
        }
    }
}

void    exit_flr(int exit_code, const char *err_msg)
{
    perror (err_msg);
    exit (exit_code);
}

void    get_map_dim(const char *file_name, int *width, int *height)
{
    int     fd;
    char    *line;
    char    *ptr;
    int     temp_width;

    fd = open (file_name, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        exit_flr (EXIT_FAILURE, "Error opening file");
    *width = 0;
    *height = 0;
    temp_width = 0;
    while ((line = get_next_line(fd)) != NULL)
    {
        temp_width = 0;
        ptr = line;
        while (*ptr)
        {
            if (*ptr == ' ')
                temp_width++;
            ptr++;
        }
        temp_width++;
        if (*width < temp_width)
            *width = temp_width;
        (*height)++;
        free (line);
    }
    close (fd);
}

int **allocate_map(int width, int height)
{
    int **map;
    int i;

    map = (int **)malloc(height * sizeof(int *));
    if (!map)
        exit_flr (EXIT_FAILURE, "Error allocating memory for map");
    i = 0;
    while (i < height)
    {
        map[i] = (int *)malloc(width * sizeof(int));
        if (!map[i])
            exit_flr (EXIT_FAILURE, "Error allocating memory for map row");
        i++;
    }
    return (map);
}

void    parse_fdf_file(t_data *data, const char *file_name)
{
    int     fd;
    char    *line;
    char    *token;
    int     x;
    int     y;

    fd = open (file_name, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        exit_flr (EXIT_FAILURE, "Error opening file");
    y = 0;
    while ((line = get_next_line(fd)) != NULL)
    {
        x = 0;
        token = ft_strtok (line, " ");
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            data->map[y][x] = ft_atoi (token);
            token = ft_strtok (NULL, " ");
            x++;
        }
        free (line);
        y++;
    }
    close (fd);
}

void    calculate_scaling_and_offset(t_data *data)
{
    int     map_max_width;
    int     map_max_height;
    double  scale_x;
    double  scale_y;

    map_max_width = data->map_width * data->scale;
    map_max_height = data->map_height * data->scale;
    scale_x = (double)WIN_WIDTH / (double)map_max_width;
    scale_y = (double)WIN_HEIGHT / (double)map_max_height;
    data->scale = fmin(scale_x, scale_y);
    data->offset_x = (WIN_WIDTH - (map_max_width * data->scale)) / 2;
    data->offset_y = (WIN_HEIGHT - (map_max_height * data->scale)) / 2;
}

After compiling this code in C when I try to open a map, it just shows that it's trying to draw pixels out of bounds. I guess it's a stupid mistake but I'm stuck on this for over 6 days and I kind of stopped..

You have all of the means to debug it. You know where the error message is being printed. Trace the bad values back from there to where they are originating from.

OTOH, I don't think drawing outside the window should be "fatal". Just don't draw the pixels that are outside.

@mell stefanova,  Why use a floating point function fabs() in fabs(coords->x1 - coords->x0) for an integer problem?  This hints that code is not compiled with all warnings enabled.  Save time, enable all warnings.

@mell t_data, t_bresenham definitions missing.  Post a [mcve].
